# How to attribuate a certain probability to each event using sample()

Tags: r, random, sample

```
mystring<- sample (1:3, size=100)
```

I want to generate randomly this string of numbers, but I want that the probability of 2 to be 0.25 and those of 1 and 3 to be 0.375 and 0.375 respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can specify probabilities using `prob=c()`

```
mystring <-sample(1:3,size=10000,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.375,0.25,0.375))
```

Output:

```
table(mystring)

       1    2    3 
    3752 2493 3755
```